# Cordova App load Facebook Profile

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, fbconnect

I want to load the Facebook Profile of a specific facebook user inside the native app.

I am currently on an Android project and have added InAppBrowser. Linking to my own FB profile with the schema fb://profile/(id) works perfectly fine. As soon as I try to load another persons profile according to this schema the native app opens and I get an error: Error loading the chronic.

Why doesnt it work loading other peoples chronic with this schema? Do I have to use a different one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does anybody have a clue?